# Should I still worry about spectre in 2020?

Tags: security, spectre

I use a laptop that has a 4th gen Intel CPU. I may soon beginn working on sensitve data.
Is Spectre something I should still worry about? Should I upgrade my laptop?

Comment: Microsoft patched all Haswell products through a Microcode update.  Only you can decide if you need to upgrade your laptop.  Be sure you do research to determine what CPUs are vulnerable to Spectre.

Comment: 4th gen will never be patched, if you can disable hyperthreading in the bios, this will stop spectre attacks.

Comment: Thanks. Not even in linux? Do I loose something by doing so?

Comment: Some vendors updated BIOS as a mitigation along with the Microsoft patches. I have done all that and I work carefully so I have been OK so far, along with my clients.